# Path options for techmap calls in a pass

Tags: yosys

I'm extending Yosys with a pass I made myself. In this pass, I call the techmap pass multiple times, with a path to the map to apply.

However, depending on the directory I'm in while calling my pass, the correct paths to the maps differ. Is there a variable that points to Yosys's main directory I can use?

The following code line shows how I currently call techmap.

```
Pass::call(design, "techmap -map passes/decompose/" + decomposeFile + " -autoproc" + tag);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The + prefix refers to the Yosys share directory - if you need an example of this, have a look at the various FPGA synthesis passes